# Hyperlink as an alternative to form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Is it possible to create hyperlinks that target specific choices from forms?

Example: I have a search form with a submit/search button. The first form element is a dropdown list containing the colours red, yellow and blue. The second form element contains the shapes circle, square, triangle.

Is it possible to create a hyperlink outside of the form to run the search queries? i.e. can I setup a hyperlink to return all red shapes.

Sorry if this explained badly.

Comment: use GET instead of POST

Comment: If it is a GET, it is setting the right query string. If a post, you need to run some JavaScript.

Comment: I give to you... [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Learn it well, and you will go far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a get, it is just a simple URL

```
<a href="myPage.php?color=red&shape=square"> Red Square</a>
```

If it is a POST, you will need to run some JavaScript to set the form values and submit it.

```
document.getElementById("color").value = "red";
document.getElementById("shape").value = "square";
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```